# Charging LiFePO4 with high voltage but low current?

Tags: lifepo4

I'm trying to charge a 230 volt 24 kW bank of LiFePO4 batteries.

It's difficult to generate the right charging voltage because it needs about 250 volts and most inverters don't do that. It's usually 220, 230, 240, 260, 300.

I was wondering if it was possible to use a higher voltage inverter but count on the voltage drop from the current not being sufficient. If the supply current is lower than the demand, then the voltage drops.

The 230V 24kW LiFePO4 bank can absorb 7,500 amps at 1C charging. So if you hook up a 15 ampere 300 volt inverter, the voltage will just fall to the optimal charging voltage and current.

Do you think this is a good idea, or will it just melt the inverter from being run on permanent overload?

Comment: Don't screw around when charging LiPOs or you will burn your house down. You shouldn't be charging LiPos directly off an inverter anyways. That's a dangerous game. How are you balancing the cells?

Comment: To be a bit more specific, *Never* charge a Li-ion battery except with a circuit specifically designed to charge it.  *Never* discharge a Li-ion battery without protection circuits(overcurrent, overdischarge and sometimes overheat).  Lithium ion batteries are potential firebombs, and assuming you meant 24kWh, that's a rather large firebomb.  If you experiment, I think you'll also find that it's very difficult to deliver 7500A to *anything*, let alone to a 230V battery without destroying it.

Comment: Hey. Well the use case makes them only go 30-60 state of charge.  This makes the balancing less important as they wont' really hit the floor or the ceiling. But besides that they are sort of self balancing because the higher voltage cells will put out more wh and have a higher proportion of the load, making itself discharge quicker in contrast to other cells. Then on the flipside the lower voltage cells will eat up more current when charging. I do believe most ev cars charge all the batteries in series without individually charging them. They do have tons of safety sensors though

Comment: @KH oh i'm not trying to put 7500 amps anywhere. I'm just trying to trickle charge this giant battery with some solar panels lol.

Comment: Are you perhaps from a country that uses comma as a decimal point?  Do you actually mean 7.5 A when you say "7,500 amps"

Comment: You risk damaging a very nice and expensive battery - possibly totally. And risk personal damage. We can help you obtain a good result BUT need more information. Please specify all that is known of battery Ah, Wh, Volts, number of cells, is there a BMS, brand and model of cells. What is your nominal AC mains voltage? || The figures given are not 'internally consistent". Is it a 7500 Ah battery. is 24 kW the max power it will supply - or is it 23 kWh capacity or ...? A full description with data as above will sort this out.  230 VAC will easily provide 250-300 volts DC.

Comment: Your suggestions re loading down a higher voltage inverter could prove disastrous. Tell us ALL that you know and we can help

Comment: These numbers REALLY don't inspire confidence. It's rated at 24kW but safe to charge at 1.75MW? No. Stop and sort out what you're really trying to do, and update the question. But the answer will be, use the correct charger, applying the correct (CC/CV/cutoff at x% of current ) charging algorithm. And err slightly on the LOW voltage side. An LFP cell has almost all its capacity between 3.1V and 3.3V so (while you can charge it to 3.65V/cell) you don't lose anything by stopping at 3.5 or even 3.4V. Mayeb 2% of its capacity but it'll live longer.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose it's 7500 amps at 3.2 volts. I guess it can absorb 120 amps at 230 volts. Not 7500 haha. But still, if the batteries want 120 amps, but the inverter can only provide 10-20, then the voltage will fall off the cliff into what would be safe voltage, provided the batteries aren't at full charge, and since they are always 30-60 soc with a load on them, that should be safe. I'm only worried that maybe the inverter's aren't designed to run at peak load perpetually. So i guess I need some kind of constant current supply. There is no factory charger.

Comment: @sergbot You are heading for disaster. You MUST provide the answers to the questions I and others asked to have any chance of success. Your "fall off the cliff" charger has potentially bad consequences for the charger and possibly the battery and is not the right way to achieve desired results. || What are the battery specs. At present it is completely unclear what is being dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't touch lipo's with anything but a very long stick, and very carefully.

You shouldn't ether.

That is a *lot* of energy stored up. Connecting anything else than the charger designed for your battery bank is a terrible idea. "Trying to do something" with a any lipo battery is dangerous. Your "lol" at the end there sends shivers down my spine. It doesn't seem like you take this seriously.

So to answer your question: No. This is not a good idea.

Comment: LiFePO4 != LiPo

Answer (score 0):

You can charge LiPo below 1C fairly safely, however, you should not go beyond the max cell voltage otherwise you will have a nice fire.

You should also not go below the minimum cell voltage.

The thing with LiPo, is that you need to perform balanced charging, where each cell voltage is checked to avoid going beyond the cell max voltage. If you fail to do so, the battery will basically do a nice firework. Check on youtube to give you an idea of the energy release.

With a battery of this size, 24kW(h?), I certainly wouldn't charge it indoors, or even in a residential area when you see what a 15Wh LiPo burning can do.

So it is not enough to just plug a 250V and charge it as the cell becomes unbalanced. Depending on what LiPo you have, it will have integrated electronics to take care of that. If it does, then this electronic should provide some level of safety.

Another issue is that your supply may go into error if it draws too much current.

With a battery of this size, you should certainly avoid playing around and use whatever the manufacturer provides, they certainly must have a specific charging unit for that.

Comment: Battery is apparently LiFePO4. Configuration and  ratings are inobvious.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can give you more feedback beyond the party poopers who just eco danger messages without much apparent foundation. Yes, risk is everywhere and so safety is invented.

I think what you would like to do is possible. I for instance charge my 12V battery with 24V solar panel and is no problem but that because I have 2 layers of safety which will cut any dangerous overcharging situation. When my 12V battery is full, the PWM is the first device to cut charging and avoid fire/explosion of the battery.

So, before you try what you mention, select the inverter that has a higher voltage than the full charge voltage of your battery. If that is 260V, then go with 260V and not a higher one. Then make sure you have a voltage regulator (PWM or MPPT) with a programable overcharge voltage cut; so when your battery reaches 250V, the charging stops. Finally make sure your LifePo4 has a BMS that also has a programmable overcharge voltage cut. This will be the second layer of defense against overcharging and make practically impossible something going wrong. This way your battery will never go over the recommended voltage; charging will be cut in the safe zone.

Given the dangers of LifePo4 and risks of your desired setup, use branded stuff and not Aliexpress devices.

Comment: Attempting to be helpful and non-negative is most welcome. | The user does not have a good idea of their requirement and care is needed in advising them. |Care needs to be taken when interpreting what 260V means intis context. The charger should certainly be set to provide only the maximum voltage required by this battery - but a 260V inverter may mean one with a maximum input voltage of 260V - and actual input should always be somewhat lower than maximum at most. || LiIon cells / batteries can be problematic. LiFePO4 are usually substantially safer and controllable.